# SQL - renumbering a sequential column to be sequential again after deletion

Tags: sql

I've researched and realize I have a unique situation.

First off, I am not allowed to post images yet to the board since I'm a new user, so see appropriate links below

I have multiple tables where a column (not always the identifier column) is sequentially numbered and shouldn't have any breaks in the numbering. My goal is to make sure this stays true.

Down and Dirty
We have an 'Event' table where we randomly select a percentage of the rows and insert the rows into table 'Results'. The "ID" column from the 'Results' is passed to a bunch of delete queries.

This more or less ensures that there are missing rows in several tables.

My problem:
Figuring out an sql query that will renumber the column I specify. I prefer to not drop the column.

Example delete query:

```
delete ItemVoid
from ItemTicket
join ItemVoid
on ItemTicket.item_ticket_id = itemvoid.item_ticket_id
where itemticket.ID in (select ID
            from results)
```

Example Tables Before:

[image]

Example Tables After:

[image]

As you can see 2 rows were delete from both tables based on the ID column. So now I gotta figure out how to renumber the item_ticket_id and the item_void_id columns where the the higher number decreases to the missing value, and the next highest one decreases, etc. Problem #2, if the item_ticket_id changes in order to be sequential in ItemTickets, then 
it has to update that change in ItemVoid's item_ticket_id.

I appreciate any advice you can give on this.

Comment: IMO this seems like a design flaw, instead of deleting the rows, use a bit flag to mark them as Inactive to then be excluded from your queries. Then you do not need to renumber the records after each delete.

Answer (score 19):

*(answering an old question as it's the first search result when I was looking this up)*
**(MS T-SQL)**

To resequence an ID column (not an Identity one) that has gaps,
can be performed using only a simple CTE with a `row_number()` to generate a new sequence.
 The `UPDATE` works via the CTE 'virtual table' without any extra problems, actually updating the underlying original table.
Don't worry about the ID fields clashing during the update, if you wonder what happens when ID's are set that already exist, it
 doesn't suffer that problem - the original sequence is changed to the new sequence in one go.

```
WITH NewSequence AS
(
  SELECT
    ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as ID_New
  FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE NewSequence  SET ID = ID_New;
```

Comment: Awesome! For those using this query remember to add a WHERE to only affect certain rows of your table.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for advice on this, my advice is you need to redesign this as I see a big flaw in your design.

Instead of deleting the records and then going through the hassle of renumbering the remaining records, use a `bit` flag that will mark the records as `Inactive`.  Then when you are querying the records, just include a `WHERE` clause to only include the records are that active:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Inactive = 0
```

Then you never have to worry about re-numbering the records.  This also gives you the ability to go back and see the records that would have been deleted and you do not lose the history.

If you really want to delete the records and renumber them then you can perform this task the following way:

1. create a new table
2. Insert your original data into your new table using the new numbers
3. drop your old table
4. rename your new table with the corrected numbers

As you can see there would be a lot of steps involved in re-numbering the records.  You are creating much more work this way when you could just perform an `UPDATE` of the bit flag.

You would change your `DELETE` query to something similar to this:

```
UPDATE ItemVoid
SET InActive = 1
FROM ItemVoid
JOIN ItemTicket
    on ItemVoid.item_ticket_id = ItemTicket.item_ticket_id
WHERE ItemTicket.ID IN (select ID from results)
```

The `bit` flag is much easier and that would be the method that I would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

The function that you are looking for is a window function.  In standard SQL (SQL Server, MySQL), the function is row_number().  You use it as follows:

```
select row_number() over (partition by <col>)
from <table>
```

In order to use this in your case, you would delete the rows from the table, then use a with statement to recalculate the row numbers, and then assign them using an update.  For transactional integrity, you might wrap the delete and update into a single transaction.

Oracle supports similar functionality, but the syntax is a bit different.  Oracle calls these functions analytic functions and they support a richer set of operations on them.

I would strongly caution you from using cursors, since these have lousy performance.  Of course, this will not work on an identity column, since such a column cannot be modified.

Comment: Hello Gordon,Do you have an example that utilizes the WITH command, You don't need to do the work for me, I just need a general example. Option 2 as a last resort, is that I'll simply renumber the rows to ensure integrity of sequential numbering, regardless if the new ID number is in a new row of data.